# Validate the presence of a single string within another string

Tags: python, pandas

By using the following code I am trying to only keep the rows from the dataset that contain the value 9 within Col_B which is a string.

The issue is that by using this code it returns ONLY the rows that consist of ONLY the string "9",
while I want to also keep the rows that contain 9 amongst other strings.

Original input:

```
   Col_A        Col_B
0      5  1,2,9,0,6,4
1      2        3,1,0
2     46            0
3    184        1,5,7
4     31            9
5     81          9,0
```

Code used:

```
desired_numbers = ['9,', ',9', ',9,', '9']
df1 = df1[df1['Col_B'].isin(desired_numbers)]
df1
```

Original output:

```
   Col_A  Col_B
0     31      9
```

Desired output:

```
   Col_A        Col_B
0      5  1,2,9,0,6,4
1     31            9
2     81          9,0
```

Please let me know if you have any recommendations! Thanks

Comment: You need to split the string into a list, then test whether 9 is in the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with string `str.contains`

```
out = df[df.Col_B.str.contains(r'\b9\b')] #str.match also work

Out[336]: 
   Index  Col_A        Col_B
0      0      5  1,2,9,0,6,4
4      4     31            9
5      5     81          9,0
```

Comment: This will work if all values in `Col_B` are within `0-9`

Comment: @BeRT2me What if there are values from 0-12?

Comment: @Alexchristof20 then still work

Comment: Still should work, but if there were a 19 for example, it'd match it.

Comment: @BeRT2me is that case modified the regex ~

Comment: @BENY The regex approach is nice as well, thanks for that! One final thing that would solve the entire problem at once is that besides some random numbers (i.e 5,6,8,9 etc), there are instances of strings in the same column such as F09218 or even P28419, is there a way with the same approach to basically just keep the instances where the 9 is by itself and never in any other format such as 99 or 109 or P28419?

Answer (score 1):

More along the lines of Barmar's suggestion, Though I think BENY's answer is more efficient:

```
out = df[df.Col_B.str.split(',').apply(set) >= {'9'}]
print(out)

...

   Col_A        Col_B
0      5  1,2,9,0,6,4
4     31            9
5     81          9,0
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I like BENY's approach, and it is more general in case there are other separators besides the comma, you can split the strings into lists using `str.split` and use `str.contains` with `regex=False` to check if the lists contain the value 9.

```
out = df[df['Col_B'].str.split(',').str.contains('9', regex=False)]
```

Or using `Series.apply`, which might be less efficient but more straightforward:

```
out = df[df['Col_B'].apply(lambda vals: '9' in vals.split(','))]
```

Output:

```
>>> out

   Index  Col_A        Col_B
0      0      5  1,2,9,0,6,4
4      4     31            9
5      5     81          9,0
```